# Ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring

При запуске моего старого проекта вышла ошибка в Eclipse под Windows, не понимаю в чём проблема ибо все раньше работало.
вот код который вывел лог ошибок:

```
package com.userfront;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserFrontApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserFrontApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError, говорит о том, что в момент компиляции класс (на который ругается) был, а в runtime такого класса нет. Проверяйте runtime classpath Вашего приложения.

Comment: есть два вида classpath?

Comment: @Ivan, Нет, он имел ввиду, тот класс, который в момент компиляции был.